# ３科目4名の試験の成績をそれぞれ割り出し二次元配列にキー入力した後に、平均点を求める

Tags: python

Pythonでプログラムを組んだが問題文のようになりません。
これのどこが間違っているのかを教えてください。
また、正しいプログラムを教えてください（この画像に似た）。

```
from numpy import *
pmax=5
mmax=4
x=zeros((mmax, pmax),dtype=int)
ps=zeros(pmax, dtype=int)
ms=zeros(mmax, dtype=int)
for p in range(len(x[0])):
    for m in range(len(x)):
        x[m][p]=int(input('>'.format(p,m+1)))
        ms[m]=ms[m]+x[m][p]
        ps[p]=ps[p]+x[m][p]
print('      科目0      科目1     科目2    平均')
for m in range(mmax):
    print('{0:1d}学生'.format(m+1),end='')
    for p in range(pmax):
        print('{0:6d}点'.format(x[m][p]),end='')
    print('{0:6d}点'.format(ms[m]))
print(' 平均',end='')
for p in range(pmax):
    print('{0:6d}点'.format(ps[p]),end='')
```

[image: Pythonでプログラムを組んだが問題文のようになりません]

Comment: サンプルコードは画像ではなく実際にここにコードを書き込むともっと回答が付きやすくなると思います！/[参考](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 取り敢えず実行してみて、それの動作状況や結果がどうなって、意図した結果になったのかを確かめてみてはどうでしょう？ それで出てきた違いを見れば何が原因かを考える切っ掛けになると思われます。今の質問内容だと動作検証やデバッグ作業を丸投げしているように見えます。

Comment: コードはマークダウンで記述してください。また「これのどこが間違っているのかを教えてください。」とのことですが何をもって「間違っている」と思われたのかを追記してください。（エラーが出たとか想定していた結果と異なっていたなどを具体的に）

Answer (score 1):

**これのどこが間違っているのかを教えてください。** についてはこんなところでしょうか。

- 3科目×4名なのに、対応するであろう最大値が何かおかしい値に設定されている。
- それぞれ定義・初期化されている定数・変数は何を表すものなのか説明が無い。
- ある時点でどの学生のどの科目の成績を入力しようとしているのかガイドになるものが何も無い。
- 「平均点を求める」とあるが平均点の計算をしていない。
- 同じく「平均点を求める」とあって個人の平均点・科目毎の平均点の両方を表示しているように見えるが、それは課題?に合っているのか明確では無い。

間違いを見つけること自身が課題である場合も考えて具体的な指摘は避けています。
プログラムの方は上記を基に問題個所を探して修正してみてください。